# What is the command to get the block height using the monerod and monero-wallet-cli command?

Tags: monerod, cli, block-height

Is there a way to output the current block height using the monerod and monero-wallet-cli command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- monero-wallet-cli `bc_height`
- monerod `print_height`

Answer (score 2):

"status" in either will show you your current height.